# Descriptor-less Jersey on Jetty 9

Tags: java, jersey, jetty

I'm looking at writing a standalone REST application in Java using embedded Jetty and Jersey.

The Jersey documentation indicates that in a Servlet 3.0 container, Jersey should be able to automatically register web applications without the need for a web descriptor file or code: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.servlet.3

However, I suspect I'm failing to correctly invoke Jersey in the correct manner (or at all):

```
        ServletHandler handler = new ServletHandler();

        Server server = new Server(8080);
        server.setHandler(handler);

        server.start();
        server.join();
```

I've tried a few other things, but most other examples seem to be trying to solve other problems.

Full example code of what I'm trying to achieve is here:
https://github.com/dowlingw/jax-rs-plzhalp

(Unrelated: I've considered using DropWizard, but don't want everything that is provided with that)

Cheers :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple example

server:

```
package com.mayapp.app;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerProperties;
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer;

/**
 * Hello world!
 */
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Server server = new Server(8112);
            ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
            context.setContextPath("/");
            server.setHandler(context);
            ServletHolder h = new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer());
            h.setInitParameter(ServerProperties.PROVIDER_PACKAGES, "com.myapp.resources");
            h.setInitOrder(1);
            context.addServlet(h, "/*");
            server.setDumpAfterStart(true);
            try {
                server.start();
            }catch(Exception ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

}
```

and the resource:

```
package com.myapp.resources;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("hello")
public class HelloWorldResource {
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getHello() {
        return "hello world";
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks - that seems to have worked... I could have sworn I tried that before, but clearly not!

It's not registering my @ApplicationPath annotated base application, but is picking up individual controllers which works just fine for me.

Cheers :)

Comment: Great, and if you like Guice, it's a handy way to do dependency injection with Jersey. [These guys](http://blog.palominolabs.com/2011/08/15/a-simple-java-web-stack-with-guice-jetty-jersey-and-jackson/) have a good example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass something jersey-related into ServletHandler, usually org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer:

```
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig resourceConfig = ...
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer servletContainer = new ServletContainer( resourceConfig );
    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder( servletContainer );

    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler handler = new ServletHandler();
    handler.addServlet( servletHolder );

    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server server = new Server( 8080 );
    server.setHandler( handler );
```

ResourceConfig provides a number of constructors and static factories that will allow you to create a ResourceConfig instance eother from an JAX-RS Application or by symply specifying a set of packages to scan for JAX-RS components.

Comment: Is `ServletHandler` in that scenario of type `org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler`?

I've tried this before but with the dependencies I've got included I don't see that constructor as an option :/

Comment: My bad, i will edit the answer to contain the compilable code.